# Rim brakes are howling , what do I do?

Tags: road-bike

Have rim brakes on my two month old road bike , and they are starting to howl when used. Cleaned the tires and rims but that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

the problem usually is that the contact between the pads and the rim is too parallel; a secret is too give the pads a tiny angle, so that the front part of the part would touch half a MM before the rear part.

Try it, it will work. I understand it might sound strange to understand, so if you have any question just ask.

Comment: This is how I have mine setup and they are silent as can be. It may take some trial and error, but eventually you find that perfect alignment.

Comment: Aka 'toe in'. Presuming you have modern calipers & brake shoes, with the little curvy washers (a friend might be helpfull to achiave this). Get a bit of cardboard or some other scrap material and tuck it behind the trailing ends of the pads then pull the brake lever so that it squeezes them against the rim, trapping the cardboard in place. Now loosen the allen bolt that holds the shoe in, and then just re-tighten it. Do this for both sides and you should find that each pad is now aligned ever so slightly closer at the front than at the back.